# Cast from '(key: String, value: [Dates])' to unrelated type 'Dates' always fails

Tags: ios, swift

As my objective is to use the MVVM architecture,I have configured my Model class fine, but now having troubles with initialising my ViewModel class. It gives me an error saying "Cast from '(key: String, value: [Any])' to unrelated type 'Dates' always fails". When I run it, it crashes. Any help would much appreciate.

**View Model Class as follow**

```
  struct JobsViewModel {

  private let title : String?
  private let imageArray : [Formats]?
  private let category : String?
  private let shifts : [ShitDetails]?
  private let distance : String?

  //Dependency injection
  init(mainData:Dates) {
    self.title = mainData.title
    self.imageArray =  mainData.client?.photos
    self.shifts = mainData.shifts
    self.category = mainData.job_category?.description
    self.distance = mainData.distance

  }
 }
```

**Model Class as follow**

```
public struct Schedule: Codable {

  public let data : [String:[Dates]]

}

public struct Dates: Codable {
  public let title: String?
  public let distance: String?
  public let client: Images?
  public let shifts: [ShitDetails]?
  public let job_category:JobCategory?

}
```

On success of my API call I'm trying to initailize it as bellow and its where it crash.

```
  var jobsViewModel = [JobsViewModel]() //jobsViewModel is a instance variable

 Network.shared.retrieveHotelDetails(successBlock: { (results) in

   let mainData = results as? Schedule
   self.jobsViewModel =  mainData?.data.map({return JobsViewModel(mainData: $0 as! Dates)}) ?? []
}
```

Comment: The error message is clear. `public let data : [String:[Dates]]` You cannot magically turn  that to a Dates by force casting.

Comment: Whats the solution in order to initialize my VM sir ?

Comment: Your api returns a dictionary where the values are an array of Dates so you need to create a new JobsViewModel for each element in those arrays. And don't tag spam please.

Comment: you are correct my api returns a dictionary where the values are an array of Dates. Is there a better way i could address this @JoakimDanielson ?

Comment: But that is not the real problem here, is it? It's your incorrect casting that you need to fix. For me it is impossible to now if for instance an array is better than a dictionary since I know nothing about your data.

Comment: "data": {
    "2018-06-07": [
      {
        "someKey": "Test1",
        "someKey": "Test1"
      }
    ],
    "2018-06-06": [
      {
        "someKey": "Test1",
        "someKey": "Test1"
      }
    ]
} would this dummy help ?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. How can there be a solution when it is impossible to guess what you are trying to do?

Comment: All Im trying to do is Initialise my VM with the sever response, and the datat structure been defined in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{"2018-06-07": [
    {
        "someKey": "Test1",
        "someKey": "Test1"
    }
],
"2018-06-06": [
    {
        "someKey": "Test1",
        "someKey": "Test1"
    }
]}
```

So you're trying to map from that (`mainData?.data` is a `[String:[Dates]]` Dictionary) to a "JobsViewModel" Array.

Your main issue is that you essentially try to map from something that contains multiple arrays to one array. If you want to do that, `flatMap` will be your best option.

Just like this:

```
self.jobsViewModel = mainData.data.flatMap({ $0.value }).map({ JobsViewModel(mainData: $0 )})
```

This first "flat maps" all of the `Dates` Arrays in your dictionary into one large dictionary that contains them all and then creates (via "map") a JobsViewModel for each of them by using each `Dates` object in the `JobsViewModel` initializer.